# Trying selectively redraw background for an android game, but the moving image is duplicated across the screen

Tags: android, opengl-es

It's easiest if I just start by showing pictures of the problem. The pictures show a snapshot of a texture moving around.

The application on my HTC Hero:

[image: Image from my Hero]

The same application on the emulator where it works fine (Disregard the randomly placed leftovers, I know the cause of them, and it's not a problem):
[image: Image from the emulator]

Now, if you look at the first image, the top one is the "real one" and the others always follow beneath, and there are copies above aswell. I am currently only repainting the background squares that was visited, and they are for some reason drawn above the copies (you can see they are all partially painted over by a tile).

Do you have to always repaint the whole screen every frame on the android phones? Or is it possible to get rid of these weird copies?

Here is the code used to draw the textures (I'm new to opengl-es so it's a lot like replica island):

first

```
public static void beginDrawing(GL10 gl, float viewWidth, float viewHeight) {
    gl.glShadeModel(GL10.GL_FLAT);
    gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_BLEND);
    gl.glBlendFunc(GL10.GL_ONE, GL10.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
    gl.glColor4x(0x10000, 0x10000, 0x10000, 0x10000);

    gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_PROJECTION);
    gl.glPushMatrix();
    gl.glLoadIdentity();
    gl.glOrthof(0.0f, viewWidth, 0.0f, viewHeight, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW);
    gl.glPushMatrix();
    gl.glLoadIdentity();

    gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
}
```

Then for every texture (I draw background first, then in this case only one hulk texture. I'm sure it's being drawn only once):

```
        gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureID);
        ((GL11Ext) gl).glDrawTexfOES(x, y, 0, (float) mWidth, (float) mHeight);
```

and at the end:

```
public static void endDrawing(GL10 gl) {
    gl.glDisable(GL10.GL_BLEND);
    gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_PROJECTION);
    gl.glPopMatrix();
    gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW);
    gl.glPopMatrix();
}
```

The code I use to load textures:

```
private void loadGLTextures(GL10 gl) {
    int[] textures = new int[1];
    gl.glGenTextures(1, textures, 0);
    textureID = textures[0];

    gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureID);

    gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,
            GL10.GL_LINEAR);
    gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,
            GL10.GL_LINEAR);

    gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S,
            GL10.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T,
            GL10.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    gl.glTexEnvf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE,
            GL10.GL_MODULATE);

    GLUtils.texImage2D(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, bitmap, 0);
    int[] mCropWorkspace = new int[4];
    mCropWorkspace[0] = 0;
    mCropWorkspace[1] = bitmap.getHeight();
    mCropWorkspace[2] = bitmap.getWidth();
    mCropWorkspace[3] = -bitmap.getHeight();
    ((GL11) gl).glTexParameteriv(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 
            GL11Ext.GL_TEXTURE_CROP_RECT_OES, 
            mCropWorkspace,
            0);
    mCrop = mCropWorkspace;
    bitmap.recycle();
}
```

All help is very much appriciated, and please leave a comment if anything is unclear!

EDIT: I should add that if I every frame redraw all the squares, the "extra" images are hidden, and it works the way it should.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Do you have to always repaint the whole screen every frame on the android phones?

Yes, and that is why double buffering is used. *Prepare next frame while showing the current frame.*

Comment: So, you simply can't save rendering calls by only rendering what's change and rely on the old stuff being stuck where it was? It works fine on the emulator though. Thanks, I'll simply repaint it all then.

Comment: Nope. I haven't seen any solution like this as long I have developed with graphic engines.

Answer (score 1):

May I know where exactly you clear the previously visited square. It is definitely possible to update just the dirty potion. But assuming you are coding with android, it maintains two buffers where swapping happens internally. In that case, you must see to that you clear the area where the image was drawn 2 frames back.

Comment: That is pretty much the reason for the leftovers in image number 2, but that will be no problem to fix. My problem is why I get the same image repeating up and down. So the one image has sort of become a whole column of images instead. The problem does disappear however, when I redraw everything. The images was never even painted in the positions it shouldn't be, and it's always straight above and under. I'm wondering if it has something to do with how the texture is handled...